# Why is my key object wrapped by special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

Hi i am beginner in c# and entity framework, when i try to populate some data why I got something like below. i need to remove '<' and '>'

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: i am using entity framework 6.4.4

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Exactly where are you seeing this? It looks more like Javascript than C#

Answer (score 0):

These fields look like the compiler-generated backing fields of the auto-implemented properties. You cannot access them directly anyway, you just need the properties themselves.

Those properties are probably named "ID", "JENIS", "KODE" and "NAMA"